# Enterprise architect use case element multilevel list

Tags: formatting, uml, enterprise-architect

I'm trying to write use case scenarios in Enterprise Architect version 13 and 
I would like to make an multilevel list in use case element. Something like this:

- List item

  - List item

The only option I found is formatting with space button. I have tried an eaforms extension but something like multilevel list it's not there. So is it some way how to write an multilevel list in EA version 13 or higher?